# Unique rows in duplicate data contained in one table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I have a table in an Oracle DB that stores transaction batches uploaded by users.  A new upload mechanism has been implemented and I would like to compare its results.  A single batch was uploaded using the origninal mechanism and then the new mechanism.  I am trying to find unique rows (I rows that existed in the first upload that did not exist or are different in the second upload.  Or rows that are non-existent in the first upload but do exist or are different in the second).  I am dealing with a huge data set (Over a million records) and that makes this analysis very difficult.

I have tried several approaches:

```
SELECT col1, col2 ...
FROM table
WHERE upload_id IN (first_upload_ID, second_upload_id)
GROUP BY col1, col2..
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;

SELECT col1, col2 ...
FROM table
WHERE upload_id = first_upload_ID
MINUS
SELECT col1, col2 ...
FROM table
WHERE upload_id = second_upload_id;

SELECT col1, col2 ...
FROM table
WHERE upload_id = second_upload_id
MINUS
SELECT col1, col2 ...
FROM table
WHERE upload_id = first_upload_ID;
```

Both of these results returned several hundred thousand rows, making it difficult to analyze.

Does anyone how any suggestions in how to approach/simplify this problem?  Could I do a self join on several columns that are unique for each upload?  If yes, what would that self join look like?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you supply your table structure and perhaps some sample data with desired results?

Comment: Oracle version? Is there a unique key per upload that you can use to correlate records between loads?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Oracle v9.1 There are several (about 7) fields that could function as a composite unique key (meaning that they would be unique per upload 99 percent of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method that might be useful is to calculate a hash of each record and run a match based on that. It doesn't have to be some super-secure SHA-whatever, just the regular Oracle [Ora_Hash()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions112.htm), as long as you're going to get a pretty small chance of hash collisions. Ora_Hash ought to be sufficent with a max_bucket_size of 4,294,967,295.

I'd just run joins between the two sets of hashes. Hash joins (as in the join mechanism) are very efficient.

Alternatively you could join the two data sets in their entirity, and as long as you're using equi-joins and only projecting the identifying rowid's from the data sets it would be broadly equivalent performance-wise because hashes would be computed on the join columns but only the rowid's would have to be stored as well, keeping the hash table size small. The tricky part there is in dealing with nulls in the join.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a join like this make sure not to include columns containing the upload-id, and any audit data added to the uploaded data.  Restrict the joins to the columns that contain the uploaded data.  The MINUS approach should work well otherwise.